# Laravel 7.30.4 How to route separate url for api and Admin

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 7.30.4 i have 2 different type of Api.

1:- Is Admin API is in admin.php (Is only Accessible from admin panel. Here is lots guard and authentication implemented, But i am new to the project.)

2:- Is User Api is in users.php (This API is accessible from android and ios App)

Both api accessible from this url

> Admin url :- https://admin.test.com/admin
>
> userAPI   :- https://admin.test.com/userApi

My problem is i need a separate url for UserApi only Like us:-

> **https://api.test.com/userApi**

What can i do For This Experts please share your knowledge. Am a beginner, i dont have much knowledge.

Comment: Isn't it redundant to have the api in both the sub domain and the path?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-setup-specific-subdomain-routing-in-laravel

Comment: @shaedrich, no. Admin api is separate(is Only used for admin related work's). User Api is For android and ios related works. In this Project i have Both in one project. admin api is maintained by admin.php and userApi is maintained in userApi.php. Both are different. Both api's accessible by this sub domain " https://admin.test.com". My requirement is how to setup specific subdomain to UserApi only. If you didn't understand, i explain it again via various ways. Thanks For your reply.

Comment: @Rwd, I ill check that link.And Update You.